# Search string, retrieve next line

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-parsing

I'm reading in a huge HTML string that has some info I need to extract from it. I can set up the search parameters (where to parse), but how can I achieve this without saving to a temp file then using `StreamReader`?

Example:

```
//Pertinent data starts here:
<!--
   body for the page starts here
-->

    <table border="0" >
      <tr>
        <td class='HeaderTD'><b>User Name</b></td>
        <td class='HeaderTD'><b>Mark TheMan</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='DataTD_Black_Bold '>Department</td>
        <td class='DataTD'>Programming</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='DataTD_Black_Bold '>Office Phone</td>
        <td class='DataTD'>555-555-5555</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='DataTD_Black_Bold '>Office Ext</td>
        <td class='DataTD'>x5555</td>
```

I need to just set some attributes in a class to the various fields (which are strings):

```
User.UserName = "Mark TheMan";
User.Department = "Programming";
User.OfficePhone = "555-555-5555";
```

etc.

You see I need to search for a line that contains something like `"<b>User Name</b>"` then return the next line so I can parse out the desired data. Let me know if you need more info, thanks!

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Html parser, [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is very good.

Here is a little console application to show you how easy is to rip the data from tables :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.Load("example.html");
  foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
  {
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
      foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Cell value : " + cell.InnerText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for your example output will be :

> ```
> Cell value : User Name
> Cell value : Mark TheMan
> Cell value : Department
> Cell value : Programming
> Cell value : Office Phone
> Cell value : 555-555-5555
> ```

Comment: i've looked at this before...however being new to HTML I have no idea where to begin. They don't seem to offer a lot of documentation. Is there a sample where I can use the parser to return the info I was looking for?

Comment: also I wanted to note, it was kind of pain to get the HTML text, the site needs specific credentials. not sure if the HTML agility pack is geared for that.

Comment: that has nothing to do with HTML Agility Pack, you have to get html and then hand it to a HTML Agility Pack. And it's really easy, try to play with HAP Explorer (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/44954#DownloadId=120936) and you will see

Comment: ahh this is very useful. I was fumbling around trying to determine what to search for with the HTML Agility Pack. thanks!